# Logging SOAP requests and responses

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

I have added a service reference to my application, with the appropriate proxy classes subsequently being generated.

In my code, I make use of these proxy classes to generate my service calls and to parse the results.

Because .Net takes care of the binding of the HTTP/HTTPS requests and responses, I am unable to view the exact SOAP requests that gets generated by my system.

How can I log the RAW http requests and responses that gets generated by the system, specifically by using Trace.Log, without having to use Fiddler or Wireshark or any other reverse proxy?

### UPDATE

It is worth mentioning the following facts as well:

- I am using Visual Studio Professional 2013
- The service I am consuming is a JAX-WS service hosted and owned by a third party.  It is out of my control.
- I am calling the service from a class library, which gets invoked from an ASP.Net MVC application (hosted on IIS7.5)
- .Net Framework 4.5

---

Comment: You should still be able to use the IClientMessageInspector solution below even if the web service you're calling is an external web service. If you add a service reference it's still WCF proxies being generated, you will end up with an endpoint reference in your config and you should be able to configure endpoint behaviour for that endpoint

Comment: @BunkerMentality Thanks. I am going to give it a go.  I knew proxies were being generated, I just was not sure whether it was WCF proxies specifically.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at implementing the IClientMessageInspector interface, it exposes two methods

**AfterReceiveReply**   Enables inspection or modification of a message after a reply message is received but prior to passing it back to the client application.

**BeforeSendRequest**   Enables inspection or modification of a message before a request message is sent to a service.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IClientMessageInspector(v=vs.110).aspx

Here's a blog post that describes an implementation that reads the message in to raw xml, hopefully you'll be able to alter that to suit your needs
http://westdiscgolf.blogspot.ie/2012/09/debugging-wcf-messages-before.html